# Cannot get rid of margin at bottom of website?

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to find where this margin originates from in the CSS, its about a 30px margin at the bottom of every web page

http://www.beatinganger.com/

Any help wold be appreciated - i know its something easy but my mind is just mush right now been working too long....

This is the css for the footer.

```
#footer{float:left; width:100%; margin-bottom:0px; border:0px solid #cccccc;  background: #333; border-top:0px solid #f0f0f0;
margin-top: 0px;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 20px;
color: #BBB;
padding-top: 25px;
}

#footer-inner {
width: 966px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
}

#footer ul li {
list-style-type: none !important;
list-style-image: none !important;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#footer a{
    color: #BBB;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#footer a:hover { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f7ab31;
    }

#footer h2 {
color: white;
font-size: 22px;
}


#footerbottom {
width:966px;
padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}





#footerbottom .copyright  {

    width: 400px;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;

}

#footerbottom a{

    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#footerbottom a:hover { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f7ab31;
    }

#footer .left_content{float:left; width:180px; margin-right: 40px;}

#footer p{float:left;  padding:30px 0 0; 
line-height: 18px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
}

#footer .left_content2{float:left; width:180px; padding-left:0px; margin-right: 40px;}

#footer .left_content3{float:left; width:180px; padding-left:0px;}



#footer .right_content{float:right; width:200px; padding:25px 10px 0 0;}
#footer .right_content img.british_logo{float:right;}
#footer .right_content ul{float:right; width:85px; list-style:none;}
#footer .right_content li{float:left; width:auto; padding-right:5px;}
#footer .right_content li.last{padding-right:0;}
#footer .block-system{display:none}
```

Thanks

Comment: ' <div id="block-block-81" class="clear-block block block-block">' sure looks suspicious to me. It comes up right before the copyright div.

Comment: Its still there without that div, that is just the copyright, privacy and terms block that sits at the bottom - thanks anyway

Comment: Describe where _exactly_.  I'm in Safari and don't see any obvious 30 pixel space at the bottom.

Comment: It is right at the bottom between the black footer and the bottom of the page - i am using chrome, but can also see it in safari

Comment: I'm in Safari (same Webkit as Chrome) and that whitespace is about 18 pixels according to my ruler.

Comment: lol at the frustrating css issue on an anger management website (I haven't figured it out yet either but I'm trying)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `#footer`.

**Edit:** Digressing a little: My humble opinion is that `float` is way over used, and when it is, it usually just causes problems.  I don't understand the point of doing `float: left; width: 100%;`.  I take a minimalist approach to CSS - only adding style rules when I'm sure I need them, and never using rules I don't understand.  Makes debugging styles much easier.

By the way... what's the story with IE?  It looks dreadful - like no stylesheets are being applied at all.

Comment: That was the better option.  Thanks Gilly.

Comment: It would still be nice to know which element was overflowing to cause this.

Comment: @Sparky - This kind of thing is usually a side effect of using `float`, especially when used with `width: 100%`.  Notice that if you change to `width: 99.9%;` the bottom margin goes away.

Comment: Didn't the usage of inserting a `.` period as part of clearing the floats contribute to this as mentioned by @Syntax Error in his answer?

Comment: @Sparky - Definitely.  TMTOWTDI.

Comment: Thanks, this is fine for now - IE should look fine as far as Im aware.

Answer (score 1):

div#footer-inner>div.copyright>div#block-block-81 is assigned class="clear-block"

Here is your culprit:

```
.clearblock:after{
content:".";
}
```

You were sticking a period after your copyright notice. It was clearing the floats, so that was pushing it below the footer.

Maybe.

You have a lot going on there. But removing just that content addition fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You have 30 pixels of top padding on `#footer p`.</s>

I'd narrow it down for you but you have about 43 external style-sheets included on that page.

**EDIT:**

After explanation from the OP, that's not the padding.  It's actually 18 pixels of white and the very bottom *under* the footer.

I agree with user Syntax Error... the root cause seems to be a "period" `.` pushed under the footer caused by class `.clearblock:after`.

Comment: Thanks, but removing that or setting it to 0px doesnt make any difference.  It is definitely somethingn to do with the footer div as I removed it on Chroome developer tools and with it gone there is no space at the bottom

Comment: the only stylesheet used in that instance is style.css

Comment: That's not the cause. I've disabled it, and the gap still remains. Besides, a `padding` increases the size of an element, it doesn't add a bottom offset.

Comment: @Jeremy: It would be easier to find if you'd point us to the relevant stylesheet or post the relevant CSS in your question above.

Comment: @RobW, When I answered, that was the only 30 pixel space I could find.  (The white space at the bottom he's calling "30 pixels" is actually 18 pixels.)

Comment: No problems, the stylesheet is style.css have included the css that is involved in the footer above.

Comment: Sparky I mentioned that it was "about 30px" - ive got no idea how much it is.

Comment: @Jeremy, You also never stated exactly _where_ it was located until _after_ I asked you in comments on your OP which was _after_ I posted this answer.

Comment: Doesnt really matter now, Syntax and Gilly came up with the answers.

Comment: @Jeremy:  How well you ask questions most certainly matters to everyone.  StackOverflow is about helping future readers as much as it about you solving your problem.

Comment: @Jeremy, and my feedback to you is to be more appreciative to those who only try to help you.

Comment: @Jeremy, I'm sorry to have hurt your feelings by being direct to the relevant point.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `height: 0;` from .clear-block:after{}. This should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer might be in you wrapper

looking at the page source I see that your footer is not included in wrapper but in html you pointed that wrapper ends after footer. right click in chrome and check what elements includes wrapper and close it properly and your problem might be gone.

```
<!-- wrapper starts ->
<div id="wrapper">....</div>  <--- here the wrapper ends
<div id="footer"> ....</div>  <---- it suposed to be here the end
<!-- wrapper ends ->
```

should be like this

```
    <!-- wrapper starts ->
    <div id="wrapper">....
      <div id="footer"> ....</div>
    </div>
    <!-- wrapper ends ->
```

Comment: HI magnum, I wanted the footer outside of the wrapper on purpose.